# discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: python, discord

I am getting this error in python discord bot in my output console:

`discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests`

but not just error a too much big html file code idk what is that. The html code I got in the error is **50+** lines long and contains some tags i dont know about like **div,script,meta**, etc.

Comment: That error is due to making too many requests which is due to a different bug but noone can tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you're making too many requests frequently at once. Discord has certain [**rate limits**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits) to its API to prevent spam, abuse, or service overload, and when you exceed them, Discord *explicitly* tells you that you cannot read more data than is allowed for a given amount of time. For further details on the error, you can read another similar post related to this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65084478/17403667)).